# Category without pushouts or pullbacks

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

Can anybody try to give a example of a category with no pushouts or pullbacks?

I want to find my own but I think an example would help.

Comment: The category of affine schemes does in fact have pushouts. And pullbacks too, for that matter.

Comment: *No* pushouts or pullbacks?

Answer (score 5):

For this kind of thing you can usually just draw an example:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
 @. A @. \\
 @. @VVV @. \\
 B @>>> E @>>> C \\
 @. @VVV @. \\
 @. D @. \\
\end{CD}
Here $A \to E \leftarrow B$ does not have a pullback and $D \leftarrow E \to C$ does not have a pushout.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the preorder with six objects $A,B,C$ and $E,F,G$. The only non-trivial arrows are arrows $A\to B$, $A \to C$ and $E\to F$, $G\to F$. Now the diagram build from $A,B$ and $C$ does not have a pushout and the diagram build from the remaining three objects and their arrows does not have a pullback.

Here is a picture of my category:

[image]